# What are Ubuntu Edge and Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-edge

I'm using ubuntu touch on a Nexus 4,dual boot.
I can see some information about ubuntu edge, sometimes ago, and it may be no longer more activities.
Could you explain/clarify the difference between them, pls?

Comment: Please could you explain a little more in the body?

Comment: Duplicate. Both topics have info even in Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Edge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu Edge is a concept of a smartphone by canonical, which has never been produced.

Ubuntu Touch is Canonical's version of Ubuntu, which is adapted to run on Smartphones.

For detailed information please read the links in the comment of user300485.